# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- YourHttpInterceptor <- $http <- ng1UIRouter

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, angular-http-interceptors

I am getting this error, struggling from hours to solve this. I'm new in MEAN stack development. 
I am trying to implement the session management in my app. But stuck at this point.

Error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- YourHttpInterceptor <- $http <- ng1UIRouter

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('YourHttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$cookies', '$location',
function($q, $cookies, $location) {


   return {        
        'request': function(config) {

            console.log("req");
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
              if ($cookies.get('token')) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('token');
              }
            return config;
        },       

        // Optional method
        'requestError': function(rejection) {
            // do something on request error 
            console.log("inside the request error");
            if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                return responseOrNewPromise
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },        

        // Optional method        
        'response': function(response) {
            // do something on response success
            console.log("inside the response ");
            return response;
        },

        // optional method 
        responseError: function(response) {
          if(response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
            // remove any stale tokens
            $cookies.remove('token');
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
          else {
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Thanks.

---

after adding the 'ngCookies'
Errors:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   MyApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module ngCookies due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCookies'
>   is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMdIcons',
    'ui.router',
    'ngCookies',
    'e3-core-ui.services', 
    'e3-core-ui.utils'  
])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider','$httpProvider','$mdThemingProvider', '$mdIconProvider',  function($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider, $mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider) { 
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('YourHttpInterceptor');
...
enter code here
```

Comment: Did you add `ngCookies` as a dependency to your application?

Comment: Can you add the code used to create the application?

Comment: basically, I want to implement the session management. so if you have any code which can help me... I can update this code. (when i add the 'ngCookies' in my app, it produces bunch of error.)

Comment: @gnerkus if you dont mind and have some time, I can share my teamviewer detail.

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you'd show how the app was created and what errors were displayed when you added `ngCookies`.

Comment: @gnerkus, 
Sir, I update the code. Please have a look..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113678/discussion-between-jatinder-bhola-and-gnerkus).

Comment: Did you add a script reference to `angular-cookies.js` or `angular-cookies.min.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step-1:
First include the latest lib:

Step-2: Include

angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngCookies',
])

Step-3: Then call the $cookies in any custom service.

Like:
app.factory('myCookies', ['$cookies', function($cookies)
{
    var profileData = {};

```
profileData.setCookieData = function (userName, userId) 
{
    $cookies.put("userName", userName);
    $cookies.put("userId", userId);
};

profileData.getUserName = function () 
{
    return $cookies.get("userName");
};

profileData.getUserId = function () 
{
    return $cookies.get("userId");
};

profileData.remove = function () 
{
    $cookies.remove("userName");
    $cookies.remove("userId");
};

return profileData;
```

}]);

That's All.

Answer (score 2):

In your index.html page, you must load angular-cookies, after you load angular.js:

**Examples**:

```
<!-- Not minified, version 1.5.5 -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<!-- Minified, version 1.5.5 -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

Notes: Try to set your versions to be the same, if you are using angular 1.5.5, then this is good. If not, make sure to set your version as appropriate.

Comment: ngCookies need to be Included

angular.module('MyApp', [ 'ngCookies', ])